# Листы достижений, пунктуация и др

Tags: пунктуация, орфография

> Важной стороной в работе с **Листами достижений** является развитие
> регулятивных умений обучающихся. При должной организации этого
> процесса учителем на первых уроках по **теме Листы** достижений
> способствуют эффективному целеполаганию, прогнозированию и
> планированию учебной деятельности. Затем с помощью этих листов
> обучающиеся могут более **осознано** подходить к процессу контроля и
> оценки собственных достижений, на основе которых под руководством
> учителя осуществляют коррекцию своей учебно-познавательной
> деятельности.

1. "... с Листами достижений..." "Листами" - с какой буквы? Заглавной или строчной? "Листы достижений" нужно ли брать в кавычки?
2. После "по теме" и перед "Листы" нужна ли запятая? (См. второе предложение)
3. Осознано. Нужны здесь, наверное, две "н"? ОсознаННо?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Определение**

***Листы индивидуальных учебных достижений*** – своеобразная выставка личных достижений ученика, в котором отслеживаются учебные достижения ребёнка по математике, русскому языку, литературному чтению, окружающему миру; а так же общеучебные умения.

Пример использования в тексте: *Можно утверждать, что Листы индивидуальных достижений – это один из инструментов формирующего оценивания.*

2. Из приведенных примеров видно, что это сочетание является составным и**менем собственным,** где первое слово пишется с прописной буквы, а в кавычки оно не заключается. Возможны варианты **сокращенных названий**, но желательно не до одного слова.

**Кавычки,** как я думаю, использовать в специальной литературе на учебную тему необязательно, если смысл термина понятен читателям.

3. Вариант *редактирования:*

*Важной стороной в работе с Листами достижений является развитие регулятивных умений обучающихся. При должной организации этого процесса на первых уроках Листы достижений способствуют эффективному целеполаганию, прогнозированию и планированию учебной деятельности. Затем с помощью этих листов обучающиеся могут более осознанно подходить к процессу контроля и оценки собственных достижений, на основе которых они  в дальнейшем под руководством учителя осуществляют коррекцию своей учебно-познавательной деятельности.*

**Примечания:**

(1) Я убрала слово «по теме», оно мне показалось лишним для понимания смысла сказанного.

(2) В наречии «осознанно» (=вдумчиво) пишутся две буквы НН, схема образования: осозна/нн/ый – осозна/нн/о.

Comment: Скажите, в последнем предложении вы оставили ***листы*** с маленькой буквы, потому что название сокращено до одного слова? Или из-за ***этих***?

Comment: Так, скопировала без особых раздумий...  Но вообще оставлять такую запись нежелательно. Как вариант, можно поставить кавычки: с помощью таких/этих "листов".  Тогда это уже будет нарицательный вариант названия, но кавычки будут обозначать, что слово употреблено в особом значении. Такие переходы вполне возможны, и это лучше, чем писать одно слово с прописной буквы.